# Show that there are uncountably many intervals in R.

Tags: real-analysis

How can I show that there are uncountably many intervals in R?

I think contradiction would work by assuming there are countably many intervals and
using that there are countable number of rational number in R, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Did you attempt to exhibit an uncountable family of intervals? Shouldn't be hard.

Comment: $\Bbb{R}$ contains only countably many **open** intervals.

Comment: Presumably you can use the fact that there are uncountably many reals. You should be able to find a function $I(x)$ such that $I(x)$ is always an interval, and $x\ne y$ implies $I(x)\ne I(y)$. Remark: Contradiction is sometimes overrated.

Comment: ^ And potentially the domain of $I(x)$ need not even have domain all of $\bf R$. @tetori: No, there are both uncountably many open intervals and uncountably many closed intervals.

Comment: How does $ \mathbb{R}$ have only countably many intervals? $ (0,a)$  for each $ a \in \mathbb{R} $?

Comment: @anon Oh, my mistake. There is no uncountable collection of  **pairwise disjoint open** intervals in $\Bbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that a set is uncountable iff it has an uncountable subset. From the set of all possible intervals in $\Bbb{R}$, we consider the subset of such intervals of the following form:
$$
S=\{(x,\infty) \mid x\in \Bbb{R}\}
$$
It suffices to show that $S$ is uncountable. To do this, we construct a bijection $f\colon S\to\Bbb{R}$ defined by:
$$
f((x,\infty))=x
$$
Hence, since $\Bbb{R}$ is uncountable, so too is $S$, as desired.

Comment: @anon I've changed my argument entirely. Hopefully this works now.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $(\alpha ,\beta)\in \mathbb{Q}^c\times\mathbb{Q}^c $. Each of these pair will give you distinct intervals. Hence set of all intervals contains an uncountable set. Therefore it is itself uncountable.